# Google Compute Engine timeout when attempting connection over VPC to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I am doing a mongoexport and then a BigQuery load of a 50 million record collection
All of my cloud functions and app engine instances connect fine to Mongo Atlas via the VPC peering connection setup via Serverless VPC Access to our Atlas hosted in GCP

However, I have not been able to get Compute Engine instances to connect via our VPC.  When I add the Compute Engine instance external IP, it connects fine.  When I remove that and add in the internal IP for the Compute Engine instance I get timeouts, but it does show:

```
2021-01-10T18:09:44.531+0000    could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, curr
ent topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: ***.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unkn
own, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp *.*.*.*:27017: i/o timeout }, { Ad
dr: ***.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connec
tion() : dial tcp *.*.*.*:27017: i/o timeout }, { Addr: ***.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unkn
own, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp *.*.*.*:27017: i/o timeout }, ] }
```

So my best guess is I'm not putting in the right IP range, or the right specific IP to allow compute engine instances to connect internally, it seems like it's Mongo Atlas firewall blocking.

What are the proper steps to setup connection between compute engine and mongo atlas over VPC so that there is no ingress/egress and connections are direct.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the [Intelligence tool](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests) on GCP to discard any firewall issue, keep in mind that the tool simulate the packet not a real packet. Once you have discard the firewall rules at GCP level, ensure that the internal firewall is allowing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess cause of this problem is firewall settings too.

Follow 2 steps below.

**Step 1. Check VPC peering status**

[image]

You can use VPC peering's internal access when 'status' is in active.

Check whether it is active or not.

**Step 2. Check Firewall rules**

If you don't have touch anything on firewall rules, Add a rule that allows each other's CIDR range at both sides.

Comment: Peering between networks is not needed when your resources are within the same network, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is the following: you are trying to access to this DNS to connect your MongoDB atlas cluster `***.mongodb.net`. This DNS is public, and your VM need to go on the internet to resolve this DNS. And because, you haven't public IP, you can't go to the internet.

The solution is to use a [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) to allow your VM to reach the Internet.

Comment: I don't want the VM to reach the internet, I want it to route to mongodb through the VPC connection so that all network transmission stays within Google Cloud

Comment: You can add firewall rules to allow them to reach only the DNS service (port 53). You only need the DNS resolution. the answer of the DNS will say you which private IP to reach in your VPC, and the rest of the traffic never goes to the Internet

Comment: @FaultyJuggler you can create a GCP Cloud DNS private zone for that particular DNS name, that way it would be resolved internally (without internet connectivity needed), or you can edit your client `/etc/hosts` file to include this manually, then you wouldn't need a DNS server for this specific DNS name

Comment: Given the error log above where it returns the cluster shard details, it seems like it's resolving DNS just fine but being blocked by one of the firewalls

Comment: perhaps it would be better to reach out the official [support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support), in order to get a full trace of where your connection is going to/from